# jQuery Trigger events (not all the time)

Tags: jquery, triggers

Say I want event A to happen all the time, but if event B were to happen, then event A should happen after event B. My event B is clicking on a div. So I want event A to always perform, but if I were to click on a div, I want that to happen before event A happens.

Using the trigger events, then event A would not happen unless event B occurs.

This is what I have so far

```
$('body').on({
    click: function()
    {
        var el = $(this);
        if( el.val() == "Select Task" ){
            el.val('');
        }

        lookUpTask(el);

        el.focus(function() {
        }).blur(function() {

            $('body').on({
                click: function(event)
                {
                    alert('This should happen FIRST');
                    el.trigger('remove_match');
                }
            },'.match', function(){
                alert('sd2');
            });

            if( el.val == "" ) {
                el.val('Select Task');
            }
            el.bind('remove_match', function(){
                el.parent().children('.match_results').remove();
            });
        });
    },
    keyup: function(event)
    {
        lookUpTask($(this));
    }
},'.task_select');
```

So on el.blur, I want to remove match, UNLESS match is clicked first. In that case, I want to process something, and then remove it.

Comment: What code have you written?

Comment: Implement observer pattern. Random workable solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590091/jquery-observer-pattern