# Can I raise my own event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

lets say I have a variable as follows:

```
var i=0;
```

If any one changes the value of `i`, I need to run some function like as follows

```
function event_iChanged(){
   alert("I Changed");
}
```

How can I do it in JQuery or Javascript ?

Comment: Check this out, might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267741/jquery-trigger-on-variable-change

Comment: JQuery trigger event was considerable !

Comment: are you looking for a way to watch variable values....

Comment: No you cannot raise your own event. If you try to do that you end up with ugly hacks. And why on earth do you need your own events? Absolutely everything can be done without your own events

Answer (score -1):

You can add a listener to your document

```
$(document).on("myEvent", event_iChanged);
```

And whenever you change the value of your variable, just call

```
$.event.trigger({
    type: "myEvent",
    message: "i changed!",
    time: new Date()
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**Solution - Mutator methods**

Maybe you should consider about using a [mutator method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method#JavaScript_example) (getter/setter) like this:

```
function SetValue(reference, newvalue) {
  console.log("Old value: " + reference);
  console.log("New value: " + newvalue);
  reference = newvalue;
}
```

*Mutator methods in non-object-oriented environments:*

> A reference to the variable to be modified is passed to the mutator, along with the new value. In this scenario, the compiler cannot restrict code from bypassing the mutator method and changing the variable directly. The onus falls to the developers to ensure the variable is only modified through the mutator method and not modified directly.

This means you should use it like this.

```
var i = 0;
SetValue(i, 10);
```

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? If someone can give me a cleaner solution to this problem, please tell me.

Comment: Same for me.. I can't understand why downvote.. bah

Answer (score -2):

A solution could be to use Observer Pattern, take a look [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590091/jquery-observer-pattern).

Otherwise, instead of creating wacther or use different plugin, you can consider to create a function that set value to x and, in add, call another function:

instead of:

```
x = 3;
```

you will have:

```
set(x,3);
```

where:

```
var set = function(v, value) {
    v = value;
    callback(v);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fq888/1/) here.